# Bootstrap tooltip for dynamically changing content

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

I use Bootstrap tooltips to create beautiful HTML tooltips for items. I basically have a skill image in the form of a .png image

```
<img id="skill" src="ice-bolt-inactive.png" data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true" title="" />
```

i define the image into a variable

```
let skillImage = document.getElementById('skill');
```

then i initiate the tooltip like this:

```
skillImage.title = '<p class="skill-title">' + iceBolt.name + '</p><p class="skill-text">' + iceBolt.description + '</p><p class="skill-text">' + iceBolt.setLevel() + '</p><p class="skill-text">' + iceBolt.setDamage() + '</p><p class="skill-text">' + iceBolt.setDuration() + '</p><p class="skill-text">' + iceBolt.setManaCost() + '</p><p class="skill-title">' + iceBolt.name + ' Receives Bonuses From: </p><p> ' + iceBolt.description + '</p>';
```

Now when i click on the skill image, i fire up an onclick function which increments the iceBolt.level++; . This successfully does that ( i also log the iceBolt.level into the console so i confirm it's changing) but the bootstrap tooltip remains unchanged (doesn't reflect the iceBolt.level, even though i've set it up to display it)

Is my usage of the bootstrap tooltip bad or is it that the bootstrap tooltips won't handle something like this. I want to use them as they are responsive and easy to use.

Comment: IBased on your updated question. I understood what you actually are looking for. I have mimicked your scenario. Use the logic to get hold of your updated data. The idea is the key. You need to take it forward from here :)

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:**

Code snipper shared, will help you update your tooltip title whenever some particular event occurs in your application.

**The idea is:** Setting my title dynamically  using a function call which returns the updated data.

```
 $("#skill").tooltip({
    placement: "right",
    title: userDetails, // userDetail() is a function which will return our updated data
    html: true,
  });
```

Function will look something like;

```
// Get user details for tooltip
function userDetails() {
  return tooltipText;
}
```

The event handler in which we update the content of tooltip.

```
 document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", () => {
  tooltipText += "Add"; // Updating my data
  userDetails();// Sending updated Title
})
```

**FULL CODE:**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  // Add tooltip
  $("#skill").tooltip({
    placement: "right",
    title: userDetails,
    html: true,
  });
});
var tooltipText = "Hello";
// Get user details for tooltip
function userDetails() {
  return tooltipText;
}

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", () => {
  tooltipText += "Add";
  userDetails();
});
```

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Dashboard</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <img
      id="skill"
      class="skill"
      src="https://picsum.photos/100"
      data-toggle="tooltip"
      data-html="true"
      data-selector="true"
      alt="skill image"
    />
    <p id="ice-bolt-level"></p>
    <button>Click Me</button>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

YOU CAN USE THE SAME LOGIC TO PROCEED FORWARD IN YOU APPLICATION.

Comment: Ah yes, well i wasn't copy pasting from my real code. In my real code it is: let skillImage = document.getElementById('skill'); That's just because for some reason i was re-typing the code and not copy pasting. In my code, they match so this is not the problem of why the tooltip only shows static tooltip and doesn't change when the iceBolt.level increments.

Comment: any ideas besides the case-sensitive? (not having a case-sensitive issue)

Comment: Yup :) I initially thought it was a typo... But now I ran the demo code on my machine ... I have given reasons why this might be happening.  In case you need more help, do let me know :)

Comment: Hi Imran, sorry i don't think i made it clear in my description. I have NO problems displaying the tooltip. It works good. My problem is that when i change something in the object's parameters, the tooltip does not reflect it, even though i call for the dynamic property inside the title="", for example - <p class="skill-title">' + iceBolt.name + '</p>. If i change the Ice.Bolt.name to something else, the tooltip does not reflect it.

Comment: Check with my updated code now: Does it reflect. I have used interpolation for these values !!! Change a value in your object. And check?

Comment: I got your question :) Main question is after the object values gets updated, the tool-tip is not modifying details :) Correct me if I am wrong?

Comment: Yes! that's it!!

Comment: Here is a JSfiddle of everything i got - (not sure why the image does not load) - https://jsfiddle.net/Skarsburning/Lc0jrod1/1/

Comment: Let me see :) what the matter is

Comment: sorry man, i can't make it work :( :( :( :( :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226526/discussion-between-imran-rafiq-rather-and-djongov).

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who is looking in the future. This solution is for Bootstrap - 5, using JQuery and Javascript.

1. Init the Tooltip

   ```js
   var tootTipTitleText = 'True or False';

   $(document).ready(function () {

       //Enable ToolTip
       $('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip(
           {
               title: tootTipTitleText,
               html: true,
           }
       );
   });
   ```
2. Remove the Previous Tooltip on Button Click

   ```js
   $('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip("dispose");
   ```

   1. Get the value to check.

      ```js
      if(checkBoxValue == true) {
          tootTipTitleText = 'true';
      } else {
          tootTipTitleText = 'false';
      }
      ```
   2. Init another tooltip

      ```js
      $('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip(
          {
              title: tootTipTitleText,
              html: true,
          }
      );
      ```
   3. Display The Tooltip

      ```js
      $('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip("show");
      ```
3. Sample HTML and JS Function

```js
function changeToolTipTitle()
{
    $('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip("dispose");

    var checkBoxValue = $("#toolTipCheckBox").is(":checked");

    if(checkBoxValue == true)
    {
        //title="Checked or Unchecked"
        tootTipTitleText = 'Checked';
    }
    else
    {
        tootTipTitleText = 'Unchecked';
    }

    $('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip(
        {
            title: tootTipTitleText,
            html: true,
        }
    );

    $('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip("show");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="toolTipCheckBoxDiv" class="form-check inputCheckBox" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" title="">
<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="toolTipCheckBox" value="true" onchange="changeToolTipTitle();" />
<label class="form-label" for="toolTipCheckBox">Check</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for Bootstrap 4:

```js
    const title = 'Your new tooltip content';
    $el.attr('data-original-title', title);
```

(Be sure not to do this instead, as it won't work: `$el.data('original-title', title);`).